# Initializing a possibly infinite array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm attempting to make sand fall from the mouse (i've changed the x and y of the sand to be the center of the canvas for testing purposes.)
I'm having some issues with one of my functions. drawSand() will not run - I believe it's because sandObj[] can't be initialized before hand, but i'm uncertain. i've tried initializing it by just limiting the array to 200 elements but that didn't seem to help any. I've added some booleans to test to see if the function is finishing and draw is the only one that isn't (besides the drawPaintTool, it's not enabled on purpose) Any help / criticism would be helpful!

```js
"use strict";

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ballX = 0;
var ballY = 0;
var ballRadius = 20;
var sandObj = [];
var sandActive = false;
var sandAmount = 10;
var sandX = 10;
var sandY = 0;
var testDrawPaintToolFunction = false;
var testPaintToolFunction = false;
var testDrawSandFunction = false;
var testMoveSandFunction = false;

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  sandAmountDisplay();
  paintTool();
  moveSand();
  drawSand();
}

function drawPaintTool() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(ballX, ballY, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();

  testDrawPaintToolFunction = true;
}

function paintTool() {
  if (sandActive == true) {
    sandAmount++;

  }
  testPaintToolFunction = true;
}

function drawSand() {
  for (var i = 0; i < sandAmount; i++) {
    sandObj = {
      x: canvas.width / 2,
      y: canvas.height / 2
    };
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(sandObj[i].x, sandObj[i].y, 5, 5);
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
  testDrawSandFunction = true;
}

function moveSand() {
  testMoveSandFunction = true;
}

function sandAmountDisplay() {
  ctx.font = "16px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillText("Sand Amount: " + sandAmount, 8, 20);
  ctx.fillText("Sand Active: " + sandActive, 8, 40);
  ctx.fillText("drawPaintTool: " + testDrawPaintToolFunction, 8, 60);
  ctx.fillText("PaintTool: " + testPaintToolFunction, 8, 80);
  ctx.fillText("drawSand: " + testDrawSandFunction, 8, 100);
  ctx.fillText("moveSand: " + testMoveSandFunction, 8, 120);
}


document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDownHandler);
document.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUpHandler);

function mouseMoveHandler(e) {
  var relativeX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft + ballRadius / 2;
  var relativeY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop + ballRadius / 2;
  if (relativeX > 0 && relativeX < canvas.width) {
    ballX = relativeX - ballRadius / 2;
  }
  if (relativeY > 0 && relativeY < canvas.height) {
    ballY = relativeY - ballRadius / 2;
  }
}

function mouseDownHandler() {
  sandActive = true;

}

function mouseUpHandler() {
  sandActive = false;
}



setInterval(draw, 10);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Gamedev Canvas Workshop</title>
  <style>
    * {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 15;
    }
    
    canvas {
      background: #eee;
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>

  <script src="sand.js">
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

so to just help out some, because if I comment the code I would most likely have to write a larger paragraph just to get this posted, i'm going to explain the drawSand function. So the for loop used is for re-drawing all the sand everytime it's called - however, i've had to set the x and y here because I couldn't think of a way to initialize something that could continuously spawn sand. I'm lost to be honest.

EDIT: Also the sandAmount is changing constantly which is most likely the problem with something like this. when the mouse is held down the sandAmount goes up - which is what paintTool is for.

Comment: Need some clarification. You say "drawSand() will not run." Do you mean the function is running and is throwing an error? You should post the error if it's throwing an error.

Comment: Rather than telling us what it isn't doing, tell us what it *is* doing.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Jacob. So, i'm actually programming through notepad - silly, I know - but I don't believe it's getting an error. If you run the code snippet it seems to just never finish the function. everything that should be true finishes except drawSand().

Comment: quick responses - thatnks. So sandObj is initialized towards the top, so I didn't think it would need to be again. @Amy it doesn't do anything besides tell me what's working.

Comment: The only things that can cause a function to never finish is an infinite loop or an exception being thrown. I'd double-check your console for errors (make sure they're not being hidden with your console filters)

Answer (score 1):

Inside of this function:

```
function drawSand() {
  for (var i = 0; i < sandAmount; i++) {
    sandObj = {
      x: canvas.width / 2,
      y: canvas.height / 2
    };
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(sandObj[i].x, sandObj[i].y, 5, 5);
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
  testDrawSandFunction = true;
}
```

...you are assigning a new object value to `sandObj`, which was previously an array. You are accessing it as an array with `sandObj[i]...` further down, so I'm guessing that was a mistake on your part. Perhaps you meant to do:

```
sandObj[i] = {
  x: canvas.width / 2,
  y: canvas.height / 2
};
```

...rather than:

```
sandObj = {
  x: canvas.width / 2,
  y: canvas.height / 2
};
```

Comment: I've been staring at this function for an hour and didn't even realize. Thanks, trying now.

Comment: That was it... I feel so silly - thanks a ton Jacob!

Comment: Glad it was that simple, we all need another pair of eyes sometimes. Have fun with the project!